# use of "SCOPE" and "SCOPE void" in C

Tags: c

I am new to C and would like to know what does these declaration means.

```
> bool SD(void) {
>     if -statement 
>      return(FALSE);
> 
> else-statement
>     return(TRUE); }   /* end - SD (void): these are written  in .c file
```

however, in the .h file, there is declared also for SD function

```
SCOPE void SD(void) //in .h file
```

is there any difference in .c and .h file for declaring SD function?

There is one SCOPE void declaration in .h file that, I didnt understand. May I ask what does it mean?

```
SCOPE void step(char dir);  //in .h file
```

Comment: If the declaration in the .h file is `SCOPE void SD(void);` and the implementation in the .c file is `bool SD(void) {...}` then the declaration in the .h file is most likely wrong. Also it's unclear what `SCOPE` is here, it's defined elsewhere in some .h file, and it's not a C thing. The declaration in the .h file should probably be `SCOPE bool SD(void);`. Anyway, it's hard to answer this question because you don't provide much context information.

Comment: Please look for definitions of `SCOPE`, most probably lines like `#define SCOPE ...`, perhaps `#define SCOPE extern` and  `#define SCOPE /*nothing*/`. This was once en vogue but it's bad style. Post your findings by [edit]ing your question. @Jabberwocky's analysis is correct, the declaration in the header file does not match the definition in the source file.